# How to create files to avoid permission issues in docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am new using docker and i have a task to create two containers: one for a django project and another for a mysql server.

I made it using Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.
The project it's working with "docker-compose up", but i have permission problems when i try to create new files inside the container with "python manage.py startapp app_name". Basically i can't modify the files inside my ide(pycharm ubuntu). For what i can understand the user in the docker is root, so i need to have root permission to change those files but i don't want to modify them as root or change the permission of those files each time i make them.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: django
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: djangopass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Comment: its better not to use root. you can create a user and copy the code to it's home dir.  RUN useradd --create-home myuser      USER myuser     RUN mkdir /home/myuser/app            WORKDIR /home/myuser/app         COPY . .

Answer (score 0):

Better not to use root user. the best way its to create a new user it give it permission as needed. copy the code to the user home directory and run the image not as root.

RUN useradd --create-home myuser

USER myuser

RUN mkdir /home/myuser/code

WORKDIR /home/myuser/code

COPY . .

Comment: i think that its better to do the following:
```RUN mkdir /app && chown myuser: myuser /app
WORKDIR /app
USER myuser```
or use